# 'Lazy loading' list of posts with pagination

Tags: plugins, ajax, javascript, infinite-scroll

I have reading settings set to show 30 posts per page, and what I'd like to do is show half of the list of posts and then 'lazy load' the remaining half on scroll. I've checked out some the available ajax/infinite-scroll/lazy load plugins, but none of them seems to have this feature or at least I have not explored much to see if the plugin supports it. So was wondering, if it's possible and if anyone knows of a plugin or snippet that can do the above?

Comment: You should try this plugin, this worked best when I needed similar on one of the blogs. **[`Ajax Load More`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/):** It's available on WordPress repo.